# How to pinch zoom in 12.04 using (magic) trackpad

Tags: 12.04, magic-trackpad

I use the magic trackpad on my desktop, and my laptop has a synaptic trackpad.  Both machines run on Xubuntu 12.04, and vertical/horizontal two-fingers scrolling work out of box, but I cannot pinch zoom on either machine.

On the other hand, I was able to pinch zoom using magic trackpad on another laptop running 11.04 (using ginn, following the recipe [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad#Using_Ginn_for_multi-touch_gesture_inputs)).

Any advice on how to restore pinch-zoom on the 12.04 machines will be appreciated.